# How to create graphs for GNN from Voronoi tessellation

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx, voronoi, pytorch-geometric

I want to do graph regression with GNN.

I would like to perform a Voronoi tessellation in cube with 3D coordinates as input, and create a graph in python by connecting the vertices of the Voronoi faces with edges.

Using the library "tess", I was able to perform Voronoi tessellation from 3D coordinates and obtain the coordinates of the vertices of the Voronoi faces and a list of the indices of the vertices of each face.

However, I could not make a graph from it. （I am thinking of using pytorch geometric or networkx to create graph.) The reason is that I do not have information on the connections between the vertices.

Is there a good way to create a graph?

```
from tess import Container

points = [point1, point2, point3, point4, point5, point6, point7, point8, point9]
#point = [x, y, z] 3-d coordinate

cntr = Container(points=points, limits=(30,30,30), periodic=False)
[v.face_vertices() for v in cntr]
> [[[1, 13, 16, 17],
  [1, 8, 2, 0, 6, 3, 12, 13],
  [1, 17, 15, 7, 10, 8],
  [2, 10, 7, 5, 4, 0],
  [2, 8, 10],
  [3, 11, 14, 9, 12],
  [3, 6, 4, 5, 11],
  [4, 6, 0],
  [5, 7, 15, 14, 11],
  [9, 14, 15, 17, 16],
  [9, 16, 13, 12]],
 [[1, 9, 5, 10, 11],
  [1, 0, 4, 8, 9],
  [1, 11, 7, 0],
  [2, 3, 7, 11, 10],
  [2, 6, 8, 4, 3],
  [2, 10, 5, 6],
  [3, 4, 0, 7],
  [5, 9, 8, 6]],
 [[1, 9, 12, 13, 11],
  [1, 5, 7, 8, 9],
  [1, 11, 0, 4, 5],
  [2, 3, 13, 12, 10],
  [2, 6, 4, 0, 3],
  [2, 10, 8, 7, 6],
  [3, 0, 11, 13],
  [4, 6, 7, 5],
  [8, 10, 12, 9]],
 [[1, 10, 13, 11, 0],
  [1, 5, 7, 3, 10],
  [1, 0, 4, 5],
  [2, 11, 13, 12],
  [2, 6, 4, 0, 11],
  [2, 12, 8, 9, 6],
  [3, 8, 12, 13, 10],
  [3, 7, 9, 8],
  [4, 6, 9, 7, 5]],
 [[1, 3, 10, 11, 0],
  [1, 5, 9, 3],
  [1, 0, 4, 5],
  [2, 7, 11, 10],
  [2, 6, 8, 7],
  [2, 10, 3, 9, 6],
  [4, 8, 6, 9, 5],
  [4, 0, 11, 7, 8]],
 [[1, 7, 6, 3, 12, 13, 9, 4],
  [1, 2, 0, 10, 11, 7],
  [1, 4, 2],
  [2, 4, 9, 8, 5, 0],
  [3, 6, 11, 10],
  [3, 10, 0, 5, 12],
  [5, 8, 13, 12],
  [6, 7, 11],
  [8, 9, 13]],
 [[1, 3, 11, 2],
  [1, 5, 7, 3],
  [1, 2, 0, 9, 5],
  [2, 11, 10, 8, 0],
  [3, 7, 6, 10, 11],
  [4, 9, 0, 8],
  [4, 6, 7, 5, 9],
  [4, 8, 10, 6]],
 [[1, 2, 10, 0, 9],
  [1, 3, 6, 11, 2],
  [1, 9, 5, 7, 3],
  [2, 11, 10],
  [3, 7, 4, 6],
  [4, 8, 0, 10, 11, 6],
  [4, 7, 5, 8],
  [5, 9, 0, 8]],
 [[1, 3, 2, 0, 8],
  [1, 5, 7, 3],
  [1, 8, 9, 4, 5],
  [2, 6, 4, 9, 0],
  [2, 3, 7, 6],
  [4, 6, 7, 5],
  [8, 0, 9]]] 

[v.vertices() for v in cntr]
> [[(0.0, 30.0, 12.291183620180867),
  (16.83297190346011, 20.771396242510807, 0.3827116483146824),
  (12.935150817539512, 30.0, 0.0),
  (3.57732045823872, 13.881291650455085, 16.029420697466094),
  (0.0, 30.0, 15.388733446735882),
  (14.032324912622842, 30.0, 25.25880093621892),
  (0.0, 24.460386836252326, 14.744158403695996),
  (24.45704382277383, 30.0, 15.035536713598503),
  (16.678776578716075, 21.96657040217616, 0.0),
  (15.083906569488269, 8.891020214237948, 16.780826532483403),
  (16.930119439664654, 30.0, 0.0),
  (15.900050552878529, 15.231888139903436, 24.854143979180158),
  (5.8834824858856765, 11.723693922914874, 14.793466836093693),
  (13.107565761948532, 12.852885937777286, 7.429016189857109),
  (18.49579772587054, 12.092873685385353, 22.61186754971291),
  (24.624848897369304, 15.3558950607982, 16.28596762309057),
  (16.11199435171129, 9.330416153178785, 14.991022151845753),
  (24.07212269237013, 14.818545673577958, 15.215443251650791)],
 [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
  (18.363581171943963, 0.0, 0.0),
  (5.883482485885674, 11.723693922914874, 14.793466836093693),
  (-1.7763568394002505e-15, 10.018542111707648, 14.433475890874568),
  (-8.881784197001252e-16, 0.0, 17.02853009678052),
  (16.11199435171129, 9.330416153178788, 14.99102215184575),
  (15.083906569488272, 8.89102021423795, 16.780826532483395),
  (0.0, 8.235279254938682, 0.0),
  (14.293124756377292, 0.0, 18.97607434215728),
  (19.90196450394991, 0.0, 9.441032124082192),
  (13.107565761948536, 12.852885937777291, 7.429016189857107),
  (12.451933634129583, 11.749968372945352, 0.0)],
 [(14.29312475637729, 2.220446049250313e-16, 18.976074342157283),
  (30.0, 2.220446049250313e-16, 6.428215030034355),
  (18.495797725870535, 12.092873685385353, 22.611867549712905),
  (15.083906569488267, 8.891020214237946, 16.780826532483406),
  (19.49927893882733, 0.0, 30.0),
  (30.0, 0.0, 30.0),
  (21.557167580731353, 10.011843409037835, 30.0),
  (30.0, 11.440994379200385, 30.0),
  (30.0, 15.905487194876216, 17.310036212487844),
  (30.0, 13.722335428884419, 12.92761569633992),
  (24.6248488973693, 15.355895060798195, 16.28596762309057),
  (19.901964503949905, 2.220446049250313e-16, 9.441032124082192),
  (24.072122692370126, 14.818545673577951, 15.215443251650786),
  (16.11199435171129, 9.330416153178787, 14.991022151845748)],
 [(0.0, 0.0, 17.028530096780518),
  (14.293124756377292, 0.0, 18.976074342157283),
  (0.0, 13.763595413843428, 16.258394204082975),
  (18.49579772587054, 12.092873685385353, 22.611867549712898),
  (0.0, 0.0, 30.0),
  (19.49927893882733, 0.0, 30.0),
  (0.0, 15.114633835123502, 30.0),
  (21.557167580731356, 10.011843409037834, 30.0),
  (15.900050552878522, 15.231888139903443, 24.854143979180154),
  (16.193612225477366, 15.749320883780168, 30.0),
  (15.083906569488274, 8.89102021423795, 16.780826532483403),
  (0.0, 10.018542111707653, 14.433475890874568),
  (3.5773204582387144, 13.88129165045509, 16.029420697466094),
  (5.8834824858856685, 11.72369392291488, 14.793466836093694)],
 [(18.363581171943963, 0.0, 2.220446049250313e-16),
  (30.0, 0.0, 0.0),
  (16.832971903460106, 20.771396242510804, 0.38271164831467885),
  (30.0, 17.106418543349214, 2.220446049250313e-16),
  (19.90196450394991, 0.0, 9.44103212408219),
  (30.0, 0.0, 6.428215030034356),
  (24.07212269237013, 14.818545673577955, 15.215443251650784),
  (13.107565761948534, 12.85288593777729, 7.4290161898571005),
  (16.11199435171129, 9.330416153178787, 14.991022151845748),
  (30.0, 13.722335428884419, 12.92761569633992),
  (16.870173141944882, 20.860941464144393, 2.220446049250313e-16),
  (12.45193363412958, 11.74996837294535, 0.0)],
 [(0.0, 8.235279254938678, 0.0),
  (12.93515081753951, 30.0, 0.0),
  (0.0, 30.0, 0.0),
  (13.107565761948536, 12.852885937777291, 7.429016189857103),
  (0.0, 30.0, 12.291183620180862),
  (0.0, 10.01854211170765, 14.433475890874568),
  (16.83297190346011, 20.77139624251081, 0.38271164831467686),
  (16.67877657871608, 21.96657040217615, 4.440892098500626e-16),
  (0.0, 13.763595413843419, 16.258394204082975),
  (0.0, 24.46038683625231, 14.744158403695998),
  (12.45193363412958, 11.749968372945352, 0.0),
  (16.870173141944882, 20.8609414641444, 4.440892098500626e-16),
  (5.883482485885667, 11.723693922914876, 14.793466836093698),
  (3.5773204582387144, 13.881291650455083, 16.029420697466097)],
 [(18.49579772587054, 12.092873685385353, 22.6118675497129),
  (30.0, 15.905487194876214, 17.310036212487844),
  (24.624848897369297, 15.355895060798193, 16.28596762309057),
  (30.0, 30.0, 16.13867651086803),
  (16.19361222547737, 15.74932088378017, 30.0),
  (30.0, 11.440994379200385, 30.0),
  (14.364009302558403, 30.0, 30.0),
  (30.0, 30.0, 30.0),
  (15.900050552878524, 15.231888139903443, 24.854143979180154),
  (21.557167580731353, 10.011843409037834, 30.0),
  (14.032324912622837, 30.0, 25.25880093621892),
  (24.457043822773826, 30.0, 15.035536713598503)],
 [(24.07212269237013, 14.818545673577955, 15.215443251650786),
  (30.0, 17.106418543349218, 0.0),
  (16.870173141944875, 20.860941464144396, 0.0),
  (30.0, 30.0, 0.0),
  (24.45704382277383, 30.0, 15.035536713598503),
  (30.0, 15.905487194876216, 17.310036212487844),
  (16.930119439664658, 30.0, 0.0),
  (30.0, 30.0, 16.13867651086803),
  (24.624848897369304, 15.355895060798197, 16.285967623090567),
  (30.0, 13.722335428884422, 12.927615696339924),
  (16.832971903460106, 20.77139624251081, 0.3827116483146673),
  (16.678776578716075, 21.966570402176117, 0.0)],
 [(0.0, 24.460386836252322, 14.744158403695998),
  (15.900050552878525, 15.231888139903438, 24.854143979180154),
  (0.0, 30.0, 15.388733446735884),
  (14.03232491262284, 30.0, 25.25880093621892),
  (0.0, 15.114633835123497, 30.0),
  (16.19361222547737, 15.749320883780165, 30.0),
  (0.0, 30.0, 30.0),
  (14.364009302558406, 30.0, 30.0),
  (3.577320458238716, 13.881291650455086, 16.029420697466094),
  (0.0, 13.763595413843424, 16.258394204082975)]]
```